# Unable to process binding on product page Magento 2.3.5

Tags: knockoutjs, magento2.3.5

Hello i'm facing an error that i absolutly not understand. I just to upgrade my magento from 2.3.2 to 2.3.5 and i have a knockout.js error on my product page and an infinite loader .
[image]
I don't no where to search  Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete answer is more investigation will be required. It appears you've got a problem with fairly core logic

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/ui_comp_guide/concepts/knockout-bindings.html#outerclick

```
The outerClick binding allows to subscribe for the 'click' event that happens outside of the boundaries of the associated element.
```

Example

```html
<div id="target" outerClick="function () {
    console.log('Clicked outside of the &quot;target&quot; node.');
    }">
</div>
```

This

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3.5/app/code/Magento/Ui/view/base/web/js/lib/knockout/bindings/bootstrap.js#L32

loads

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3.5/app/code/Magento/Ui/view/base/web/js/lib/knockout/bindings/outer_click.js

Is outer_click.js still exist/loading correctly?

Failing that see if you can find the outerClick binding in your theme template. Could remove if you don't think it's required.